# xrdp setup over ssh

Tags: ssh, xrdp

Here are the steps to install xrdp on ubuntu 12.04 and get it working:

> http://www.ubuntututorials.com/remote-desktop-ubuntu-12-04-windows-7/

However, I want a secure xrdp connection over ssh and I am able to achieve it by using port forwarding in the software putty as below:

> L1234 ==> localhost:3389

But I am still able to remote login to the ubuntu through xrdp connection **when I am not connected using SSH**.

It is supposed to deny remote login when SSH is not present.

In the file

> /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini

I tried to change the [global] section by adding "ip=127.0.0.1" and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the xrdp.ini parameter that controls the listening interface IP is called 'address' not 'ip' i.e. in the globals section:

```
[globals]
address=127.0.0.1
```

At least, this works for me - however note that I am using a source-built xrdp from http://scarygliders.net/x11rdp-o-matic-central-downloads-page/ so I can't guarantee it is supported in the default packaged version.

The closure of the port can be confirmed by running netstat on the remote host, or using nmap i.e. before adding 'address=127.0.0.1' to the [globals] section:

```
$ sudo nmap -p 3389 192.168.1.16

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-08-05 02:08 UTC
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.16
Host is up (0.0065s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
3389/tcp open  ms-term-serv
```

After adding the 'address' parameter and restarting the service

```
$ sudo nmap -p 3389 192.168.1.16

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-08-05 02:10 UTC
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.16
Host is up (0.030s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
3389/tcp closed ms-term-serv
```

Also note that at least in Windows 7, the native Remote Desktop Connection client appears to have trouble if the remote server is tunneled to localhost:3389 (the default xrdp port), I ended up setting my putty tunnel as

```
L33389    localhost:3389
```

and then specifying localhost:33389 in the Remote Desktop Connection dialog (although any suitably high numbered free port should work as well)

Answer (score 0):

I having problems getting connected from Windows 7 by using remote login. I've found a good site that explains a lot.

- [Ubuntuwiki.net / Xrdp, installing](http://ubuntuwiki.net/index.php/Xrdp,_installing)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.