# Make certificate compulsory for RDP into Ubuntu machine along with username password combination

Tags: xrdp, openssl, rdp, certificates

I am setting up RDP connection in Ubuntu and trying to access it from another machine (Windows/Mac, via Microsoft's `Remote Desktop Connection`). The setup is fine and works properly with username and password.

However, we want to make it secure by ensuring that RDP is allowed only if a certificate is specified (much like public-private key pair used in SSH) along with password input. I ran the following command in my Ubuntu machine (used no passphrase):

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout private.key -out public.cert -days 365
```

It generated a cert file and a key file which I am trying to use in the `ini` file for XRDP (`/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`) along with some other changes in settings:

[image]

After this I restart the service:

```
sudo systemctl restart xrdp
```

But even after this, I am able to connect to the machine via RDP from Mac, it does not ask for certificate (I also don't know how to provide one if it asks, since the `Remote Desktop Connection` app does not provide any affordance to specify certificate while making a new connection except asking for host IP address, username and password).

Any idea on

1. How to make sure that only with certificate can one RDP into the Ubuntu machine (along with username and password inputs)?
2. How to use the certificate to RDP from Mac and Windows `Remote Desktop Connection` apps?

Not sure if that instruction on adding `xrdp` user to `ssl-cert` group has any bearing on this.

Comment: I don't know much about certificates to tell you if it can be done. But I know you can use a ssh tunnel to xRDP. Remmina, an Ubuntu client app can be configured to use ssh+xrdp.

Comment: See [this question about xrdp setup over ssh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202011/xrdp-setup-over-ssh) for some details. Also see [this blog post](https://www.cloudthat.com/resources/blog/a-guide-to-access-rdp-through-ssh-tunneling-using-putty)

Comment: Any help here, folks?

Comment: I didn't think there is a way to do what you want except by using an ssh tunnel.